# UIButton with a different size after is load

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, gradient

Hi I'm trying to put a  gradient background in an UIButton. This is my method but for the iPhone 7 plus or 8 plus it does not cover all the button. When a see the uibutton frame (174.5, 0.0, 164.5, 47.0) but after is load I can see that is (194.5, 0.0, 184.5, 47.0). It looks like this
[image]

```
func setRedGradiant(){
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:0.5).cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 4
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    print(self.frame)
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
    gradient.colors = [
        UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.34, blue:0.39, alpha:1).cgColor,
        UIColor(red:0.94, green:0.17, blue:0.2, alpha:1).cgColor
    ]
    gradient.locations = [0, 1]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    gradient.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
    self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
}



@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: UIButton!{
        didSet{
            signInButton.setRedGradiant()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling setRedGradiant in viewDidLoad ? If that is the case, then it would certainly show the frame wrt the storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your `@IBOutlet` is set, `view` doesn't has correct frame. I suggest you to learn more about `UIViewController lifecycle` to understand this problem.

Correct solution for you will be to call `setRedGradiant` for appropriate button on `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method.

This [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) is called each time when your view bounds is changed.

Comment: Thanks that solve the problem!! is any way to call the method in the IBOutlet?? Jus for the code order

Comment: You can calculate expected button size by using your screen size. Call `UIScreen.main.bounds` for this.

Answer (score 1):

The gradient's frame needs to be set after the size of the button has been established.  One handy way to do that is to create a subclass of `UIButton` and override `layoutSubviews` to set up the gradient.

`layoutSubviews()` will be called anytime the frame of the button changes, but you'll only want to set up the gradient the first time.  Use a property to store the gradient so that you can update the `frame` on later calls.

```
class GradientButton: UIButton {

    var gradient: CAGradientLayer?

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setRedGradient()
    }

    func setRedGradient() {
        if gradient == nil {
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
            self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:0.5).cgColor
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 4
            self.gradient = CAGradientLayer()

            self.gradient?.colors = [
                UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.34, blue:0.39, alpha:1).cgColor,
                UIColor(red:0.94, green:0.17, blue:0.2, alpha:1).cgColor
            ]
            self.gradient?.locations = [0, 1]
            self.gradient?.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
            self.gradient?.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)

            self.layer.addSublayer(self.gradient!)
        }

        // Always update the frame, even if this isn't the first call
        self.gradient?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        self.gradient?.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
    }
}
```

To use this in the Storyboard, change the `class` of your `UIButton` to `GradientButton` in the *Identity Inspector*.

Your outlet becomes:

```
@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GradientButton!
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that the button sets and updates its own gradient which is nice if you have two or more buttons.

A future improvement would be to make the colors a property so that you could have more than just red buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should call `signInButton.setRedGradiant()` at `viewDidLoad`, also use `.bounds` instead of `.frame` at function:

```
func setRedGradiant(){
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:0.5).cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 4
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    print(self.bounds)
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: self.bounds.size.height)
    gradient.colors = [
        UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.34, blue:0.39, alpha:1).cgColor,
        UIColor(red:0.94, green:0.17, blue:0.2, alpha:1).cgColor
    ]
    gradient.locations = [0, 1]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    gradient.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.height / 2
    self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
}
```

Comment: I try to use bounds before. I think that the only option is to call it in viewWillLayoutSubViews